# AWS IoT core data to dynamodb not all data is being received in the db

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-iot-core

I use my IoT core to act as an MQTT broker to collect sensor data. This part works fine and everything looks correct when testing it in the test environment. The IoT core passes the data to a dynamodb table and here is where it goes wrong. I'm not receiving all the data as the IoT core does. I should have every 10-40 seconds some data but the dynamodb register sometimes with a gap of 5 minutes and other times it has gaps from over a couple of hours. Is there some kind of setting which I need to change or how to fix this that I'm not losing any data while transporting it to Dynamodb?

Data comes in this format on the test explorer:

```
> {   "GEG_BUF2_LT01_M3": "477.4305",   "GEG_BIO1_TT_01": "8.709491",  
> "STATUS_BIO2_P_02": "0",   "STATUS_BIO1_S_01": "0",  
> "STATUS_BIO2_P_01": "0",   "M_alarm": "0",   "M_nieuw_alarm": "0",  
> "time": "2022-12-04 20:48:01" }
```

[Dynamodb table picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxXUv.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your data sometime ends up in Dynamo, it's possible your query fails to match data or more likely that some malformed data is causing parsing to fail. Try adding an error action that writes to S3 or SNS so you can see what is failing.

Alternately [enable IoT logging and use Cloudwatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/cloud-watch-logs.html) to debug.

Answer (score 0):

What is the primary key for your DynamoDB table?

Have you checked your DynamoDB table metrics for throttling, which can result in writes now being persisted?

How are you ensuring the iot sensor emitted data for the time which is missing from the table?